# Run individual command as another windows user within batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch file (in Jenkins). I would like to run only "SqlPackage.exe" command as another windows user. I have the domain user id and password for it.

Batch file:

```
CD Folder_Name
DEL Another_Folder
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Script /sf:DB.dacpac /Profile:publish.xml /TargetServerName:Server1   /op:Publish.sql
Copy Publish.sql Somewhere_Folder
```

I understand I can run the batch file as another user using windows `runas` feature. However, in this case, I would like to only run an individual command (sqlpackage.exe).

Is it possible?

Comment: `psexec \\computername -u domain\user -p password SqlPackage.exe /Action:Script /sf:DB.dacpac /Profile:publish.xml /TargetServerName:Server1   /op:Publish.sql`

This should work

Comment: `runas /?` shows you how to do that (see the last two examples)

Comment: @DevX - Thanks for your comment. psexec requires additional executable. Is there anything built it?

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks for your comment. It looks like runas does not allow to password so I wont be able to use it without user interaction.

Comment: @developer I think you should look at the following [link](https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-command-as-a-different-user-in-powershell/) and then further into the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` and `System.Diagnostics.Process` and then run your command or subscript as a **Process** where **ProcessStartInfo** can contain the User and Password.